# Why there isn't a complete RootMeanSquareError output when using pcregrigid methods in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

```
ptCloud = pcread('draft.ply');
ptCloud2 = pcread('draft2.ply');
[tform,rmse] = pcregrigid(ptCloud,ptCloud2,'Extrapolate',true)
```

However, the output is not complete:

```
tform = 

  affine3d - 属性:

                 T: [4×4 double]
    Dimensionality: 3


rmse = 

  pointCloud - 属性:

     Location: [47746×3 single]
        Color: []
       Normal: []
    Intensity: []
        Count: 47746
      XLimits: [-816.5720 1.3465e+03]
      YLimits: [-275.4660 537.1106]
      ZLimits: [-1.8257e+03 -921.1833]
```

At first, I thought the problem might be caused by the different sizes of the two point clouds, so I modified these point clouds to 45,000 elements, but it is still not working. You can download the files from the link below:

URL：https://pan.baidu.com/s/15HUpL2ImK0k1TPgHnLivIA

password：9hfo

Comment: Are those non-English characters because you installed MATLAB in that language, or did you actually use those somehow as variables?

Comment: As I don't have the Computer Vision Toolbox (which `pcread` and `pcregrigid` are a part of), nor the files `draft.ply` and `draft2.ply`, I can't really run the code to confirm. The [pcregrid documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/pcregrigid.html) is also somewhat unhelpful as to what is the output supposed to look like. Im guessing, possibly, your original point clouds did not have a property of intensity(?), or otherwise there is something they were missing for `pcregrigid` to calculate all of the output.

Comment: Also; the documentation suggests to use [`pcregistericp`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/pcregistericp.html) instead of `pcregrigid`. Maybe that would solve your problem? This would, though, depend on your version of Matlab, as `pcregistericp` was introduced much later (2018a) than `pcregistericp` (2015a).

Comment: Also, also; you might want to consider running `format short; format compact;` befor pasting the command line output from matlab. (It makes it, funnily enough, short and compact)

Comment: @Adriaan Because I installed a Chinese version, those characters mean attribute.

Comment: @MarcinKonowalczyk Yes, I cannot use the latest method cause my Matlab is 2017a version

Answer (score 0):

The problem is already solved.
The previous outcome variable "rmse" is actually a point cloud.
I tried to modify the variable rmse to the third output argument.

```
[tform,temp,rmse] =pcregrigid(ptCloud,ptCloud2,'Metric','PointToPoint','Extrapolate',true)
```

then it can output the result normally.